# How to get dictionary functionality from a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dictionary, dataframe

R doesn't seem to have a dictionary structure. Let's say I have a data.frame of people who have unique first names (keys):

```
people = data.frame(c("Bob", "Jones"), c("Sally", "Smith"));
names(people) = c("Firstname", "Surname");
```

I want to know what `Sally`'s `Surname` is, only knowing her `Firstname`.

I could write some ugly code that traverses `people$Firstname`, keeping track of an index, and then fetching `people$Lastname` at that index once I find a match, but this probably isn't the right way.

What's the "R way" to do this?

Comment: R does have dictionary-like structures: lists and environments. What do you need that isn't explained by any of the search results from [\[r\] dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+dictionary)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think your data frame is crafted the way you think it is. Using this one, it's pretty simple:

```
people <- data.frame(Firstname=c("Bob", "Sally"),
                     Surname=c("Jones", "Smith"), 
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

people[people$Firstname=="Sally",]$Surname
## [1] Smith
```

You could also craft it as a list:

```
ppl <- list("Bob"=list(Surname="Jones"),
            "Sally"=list(Surname="Smith"))

ppl[["Bob"]]
## $Surname
## [1] "Jones"
```

Answer (score 2):

For fun, for this particular example that you've provided, you can also use the `person` function in base R. Here, I've used `as.person`:

```
people <- c(as.person("Bob Jones"), as.person("Sally Smith"))
str(people)
# List of 2
#  $ :Class 'person'  hidden list of 1
#   ..$ :List of 5
#   .. ..$ given  : chr "Bob"
#   .. ..$ family : chr "Jones"
#   .. ..$ role   : NULL
#   .. ..$ email  : NULL
#   .. ..$ comment: NULL
#  $ :Class 'person'  hidden list of 1
#   ..$ :List of 5
#   .. ..$ given  : chr "Sally"
#   .. ..$ family : chr "Smith"
#   .. ..$ role   : NULL
#   .. ..$ email  : NULL
#   .. ..$ comment: NULL
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr "person"

people$given
# [[1]]
# [1] "Bob"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Sally"

people[people$given == "Bob"]
# [1] "Bob Jones"
people[people$given == "Bob"]$family
# [1] "Jones"
```